# OrbitalControls 'THREE.Spherical is not a constructor' Error

Tags: javascript, three.js

When trying to use OrbitalControls.js in my Electron app, I get the following error about the Spherical constructor.

```
Uncaught TypeError: THREE.Spherical is not a constructor
```

I'm having trouble finding a Sphereical.js file anywhere to fix this error. Where is this file, or am I doing something else wrong?

The error points to line 249 in OrbitalControls.js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure the source code of `OrbitControls.js` is from the same release as the three.js library. Update both to the current version.

three.js r.75